# Making unique screen transitions - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have two screens and want to change the `SlideTransition` from my second to first screen to `direction: 'right'` while keeping the first to second transition the default. The docs only show how to change the transition for every transition. How would I make a transition unique to one screen, done in the kv file?

Note: I have declared my screen manager screens in the kv file also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a property that lets you simply do this - the transition is a property of the screenmanager, not of the screen.

You could add your own screen change method for the screenmanager that knows about the screen names and internally sets the transition.